# PHP Obscured URL for Resized Images

Tags: php, image, apache2, image-scaling, mod-expires

We cache images in multiple sizes.

Image Information:

- Original URL: http://www.example-store.com/images/some-image.jpg
- Width: 120
- Height: 150
- Preferred Image File Name: image-file-name.jpg

So we build the following image cache URL:

http://cache.example.com/image/120x150/ksjdaflkj678687TYTGGGShjk78/image-file-name.jpg

When this URL is requested, http://cache.example.com/image/120x150/ksjdaflkj678687TYTGGGShjk78/image-file-name.jpg , this is rewritten behind the scenes (htaccess type of thing) into: http://cache.example.com/image.php?height=120&width=150&originalUrlHashed=ksjdaflkj678687TYTGGGShjk78&preferredFileName=image-file-name.jpg

The hashed image is decoded, downloaded from the original location, resized and physically saved here: /image/120x150/ksjdaflkj678687TYTGGGShjk78/image-file-name.jpg . **Why?** Because on the second request, the file physically exists on the disk and is returned as a normal file and then we can use apache2 mod_expires caching and not download and resize the image on every request.

The problem is with a remote image URL like this:

- http://i.dell.com/das/xa.ashx/global-site-design%20WEB/03633057-bbb8-b132-bf2c-42c0da53fa21/1/OriginalPng?id=Dell/Product_Images/Dell_Client_Products/Notebooks/Inspiron_Notebooks/Inspiron_15rse/bestof/laptop-inspiron-15rse-7520-generic-bestof-500-ng.psd

The Original Image Hash is:

- eNptzbtOAzEQheGnoZwdr40JQkJIBIo0kI5y5cusM4pjWx4j5fFJICXt_x3pHMZoT4g8Rcp5CvWE0Qme3eTkcMaUq3cZhAdBJOFU7rT6en9FZR6MUXYD3vtH8LPR4Fcd4F4HFZ01q9MzzvjZOXFxeV_SC8fnt8sH7nuN32Esu5NLJHhtyzYzlbHcSPCjDvK1HgV3RRr3WpZ_0my7EHqSUVfMro3agG8IvwgbqxUkKtQ5wN8SrFJQ0tQk_gCey1fZ

Which makes the URL look like this:

- http://cache.example.com/image/150x125/eNptzbtOAzEQheGnoZwdr40JQkJIBIo0kI5y5cusM4pjWx4j5fFJICXt_x3pHMZoT4g8Rcp5CvWE0Qme3eTkcMaUq3cZhAdBJOFU7rT6en9FZR6MUXYD3vtH8LPR4Fcd4F4HFZ01q9MzzvjZOXFxeV_SC8fnt8sH7nuN32Esu5NLJHhtyzYzlbHcSPCjDvK1HgV3RRr3WpZ_0my7EHqSUVfMro3agG8IvwgbqxUkKtQ5wN8SrFJQ0tQk_gCey1fZ/laptop-inspiron-15rse-7520-generic-bestof-500-ng.jpg

The Hash part of this URL is more than 255 characters and this makes Apache Error - https://serverfault.com/questions/120397/max-length-of-url-257-characters-for-mod-rewrite

EDIT: Just to add - the issue is with the length of the hash. With a hash under 255 chars, this solution works perfectly.

There are several considerations here:

1. The cache URL is on a different server from that calling it. They do not share a database, so the Original URL must be included in the URL.
2. I need to hash the URL and use the hash as the directory name so that we can physically save the resized file to disk for future requests.
3. This means that on request one - it magically craetes the file and saves it to disk. On request two, it just returns the physical image.
4. If cache.example.com and the website that is calling the URL were on the same server, and could share a database, then we could save the image URL into a table and return a hash or key or something. Unfortunately, this is not an option.

Solutions?

- The only solution I can think of is compressing the URL somehow. However, since I need to (and I do) base64 encode it to make it work along the URL, this adds extra size to it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The problem I have is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807518/php-shorter-obscured-encoding-for-a-url-embedded-in-another-url).

Comment: Just to add - the issue is with the length of the hash. With a hash under 255 chars, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: What hash algorithm are you using that's almost as long as the original data?

Comment: Hi  Álvaro G. Vicario, $hash = strtr(base64_encode(gzcompress($url, 9)), '+/=', '-_~'); And the opposite to decode. Of course it's not a hash as such. It has to be decodable so I have retrieve the URL.

Comment: In the beginning I was just base64encode'ing the URL. However, I added gzcompress when it became too big before. Then certain stores have now increased their image URL lengths - so the problem cropped up again. I cannot think of any way to reduce the hash size. The hash is just a base64 encoded string containing the URL.

Comment: I just want to clarify. The image cache application is a stand alone application from the website that calls it.  The two applications do not share a database of any other type of storage. The original image URL must be given to the cache server.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, a URL could hold up to 2083 characters. I doubt there's an algorithm to make that fit in less than 255 US-ASCII characters.

Since you appear to be the one that generates the URLs in the first place, I'd simply store the target URL on the server (e.g. in a database table) and use its associated ID (or an actual hash). Then, it'll be trivial to fetch the URL from the ID or hash.

The GET method is not designed to transmit large amounts of data.

**Edit:**

My answer is apparently not clear enough so I'll try to clarify it.

Let's say you want to link to `http://www.example.com/media/test.jpg`. So far, you obfuscate `http://www.example.com/media/test.jpg` as e.g. `uggcabcjjjwrknzcyrmpbzjzrqvnxgrfgwwct` and generate a URL like this:

```
http://cache.example.com/image/150x125/uggcabcjjjwrknzcyrmpbzjzrqvnxgrfgwwct
```

My advice is that you store the URL into a database table:

```
url_id url
====== =====================================
     1 http://www.example.com/media/test.jpg
```

... and you create a URL like this:

```
http://cache.example.com/image/150x125/1
```

When you mod_rewrite the URL, you run this query:

```
SELECT url
FROM url_cache
WHERE url_id=1
```

... and, voilá!, you have `http://www.example.com/media/test.jpg` back without the need to transmit it in the URL.

Alternatively, you can store and use a *real* hash:

```
url_id url                                   hash
====== ===================================== =====
     1 http://www.example.com/media/test.jpg ae4a962c5c40dc8d59554a503719ce445c047246837c7203d319cd5b0b5b3703
```

... and:

```
http://cache.example.com/image/150x125/ae4a962c5c40dc8d59554a503719ce445c047246837c7203d319cd5b0b5b3703
```

Since it's a real hash rather than an obscured text you know the size before hand.

Comment: The problem is not with the length of the URL. The problem is with the length of the hash. If it is more than 255 characters, apache2 is assuming that it is too long. The maximum size of a folder or filename is 255 characters. In the example above the hash is >255 characters, meaning that the directory size being requested on the address bar is >255 characters and apache is rejecting the request. Additionally, I could not create the folder and save the resized image to disk with the hash this long as the O/s will not create a folder with the name that long. I need to reduce the hash size.

Comment: Re: I'd simply store the target URL on the server (e.g. in a database table) and use its associated ID. As I said above, "The cache URL is on a different server from that calling it. They do not share a database, so the Original URL must be included in the URL." Your suggestion would be viable if they both had access to the same DB - but they do not :(

Comment: Alright, just seen your second message. I thought you hadn't understood the answer.